# Banco de dados em tupla

Tags: python, algoritmo, dicionário, tupla

Preciso de um código que receba dados (valores) e que os imprima de acordo com sua chave. Cada entrada corresponde a um dado de uma pessoa hipotética, que contém Idade, Nome, Sexo, Estado Civil, Número de amigos e Número de Fotos. Estou escrevendo utilizando um dicionário que recebe as entradas como valores e os relaciona com as chaves. Como fazer isso utilizando Tuplas e de forma que os dados sejam impressos na ordem em que foram fornecidos pelo usuário? Como estou fazendo:

```
Dados = dict()
entrada1 = raw_input()
entrada2 = raw_input()
entrada3 = raw_input()
entrada4 = raw_input()
entrada5 = raw_input()
entrada6 = raw_input()
Dados['Idade'] = entrada1
Dados['Nome'] = entrada2
Dados['Sexo'] = entrada3
Dados['Estado'] = entrada4
Dados['Amigos'] = entrada5
Dados['Fotos'] = entrada6
for chave, valor in Dados.items():
    print chave, valor
```

Além disso, o código não está imprimindo as chaves e os valores de forma que um dado apareça por linha, e sim imprimindo o dicionário inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples é usar o `OrderedDict` em vez do `dict` embutido - `OrderedDict` é uma estrutura de dados semelhante a um dicionário, disponível no módulo `collections` da biblioteca padrão - mas que diferente de um dicionário normal, preserva a ordem em que os pares de chave e valor foram criados quando se intera sobre o mesmo.

Desta forma, tudo o que você precisa fazer no seu programa é importar o OrderedDict e declarar `Dados` como sendo um deles - o restante você pode deixar como está:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
Dados = OrderedDict()
...
```

Comment: Meu problema é que o usuário é quem determina a ordem dos dados. Se ele quiser começar com Nome, depois Idade, depois Amigos, enfim.. Eu preciso escrever o código de uma forma cada dado fornecido seja "automaticamente" relacionado com o seu tipo. Se a pessoa digitar um nome, sua chave deve ser Nome. Se digitar M, sua chave deve ser Genero. S - Estado Civil (solteiro), e assim por diante. Não posso determinar que o primeiro dado digitado seja usado como Nome, por exemplo. Essa é a minha trava.